# Firefox hr opacity display different

Tags: html, css, firefox, opacity

```
<hr style="opacity:0.4" />
```

I have problem with firefox hr opacity, it works fine on all other browser expect firefox

anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Works fine for me. What version of Firefox. Do you have other code that might affect it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works as it should but I think you are talking about the 3d kinda default `hr` rendering of Firefox for `hr`, inorder to make the style consistent throughout browsers, reset the `border`, and apply the `border` again

```
hr {
   border: 0;
   border-top: 1px solid #f00;
   opacity: .1;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/2crVW/)

You can also use [`rgba()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value#rgba%28%29) if you do not want to use `opacity` like

```
border-top: 1px solid rgba(255,0,0,.1); //Equivalent to opacity: .1; for red color
```

---

On the other hand, if you want, you can also declare an attribute called `noshade="noshade"`

```
<hr style="opacity:0.4" noshade="noshade" />
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/2crVW/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Lets try this:

```
opacity:0.5 /*All modern browser support*/
-webkit-opacity: 0.5; /*For webkit browser*/
-moz-opacity: 0.5; /*For Firefox Browser*/
filter:alpha(opacity=50);/*For IE8 and lower*/
```

Comment: only older versions. The newest versions support `opacity` as a standard now.

Comment: I know modern browser support opactiy. no need to use -moz-, webkit, -khtml. but can you sure that all user on internet using the latest browsers?  -moz and -webkit have added just for fallback if any user still using older browser.

Comment: Firefox [supports `opacity`](http://caniuse.com/css-opacity) property from version 2.0, so do you think OP is using firefox 1.0?

Comment: @Mr.Alien you are right -moz-opacity doesn't work anymore on firefox since version3 was comes. thanks for sharing information.